# C# Generic function constrain dictionary argument to keys and values in class

Tags: c#, generics

I want to write a generic function in C# that does an operation on a Dictionary that is constrained to only have the keys and values of that generic.

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get<T>(Dictionary<???, ???> dictOfT)
{
  ...
}
```

But I don't know what to put in the place of `???`.

Ideally I would then be able to call it with a class such as this.

```cs
public class MyJsonClass
{
  [JsonProperty("name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [JsonProperty("url")]
  public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Then I would be able to call it and know that the only things that I can specify in the Dictionary I give to the function `Get` would be defined in `MyJsonClass`.

```cs
Get<MyJsonClass>(new Dictionary<???, ???>() { { "name", "George" } });
```

I tried different ways to do this, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Comment: It looks like you can use `Dictionary<string, object>`?

Comment: That doesn't really give me the type safety that I am after. It will then allow any string and object pair even if they don't exist in my `MyJsonClass` class.

Comment: Surely you are getting the JSON from somewhere else right? There is no way the compiler can check whether `Get<MyJsonClass>(aRandomDict)` is safe.

Comment: Please clarify the type safety, Isn't "George" an arbitrary string? How would you get the value of "url"?

Comment: why do you even want that? Seems like you want to deserialize your json, so just use existing framework `JsonConvert`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get<T, U, V>(Dictionary<U, V> dictOfT)
{
  ...
}
```

Type parameters have to be declared within angle brackets after the method name.

To call the above generic method

```
Get<MyJsonClass, string, string>(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "name", "George" } });
```